# A large update request at once?

Tags: mysql, bulkupdate

In my code I build a CASE WHEN statement through a foreach loop in order to update some data.

The thing is I might end up with a hundred lines statement or even more and I'm wondering if it safe to use a such a large update request at once. Should I divide my request into small chunks instead?

Basically the table is structured as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE 'table_example' (
'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_1' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_2' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_3' DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
'attr_4' DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
'attr_5' TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_6' TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_7' TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_8' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_9' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
'attr_10' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
'attr_11' TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL , 
'attr_12' TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
INDEX 'idx_id' ('id' ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

Once built, the CASE WHEN statement might look something like this:

```
CASE attr_1  
WHEN id = 1 THEN 5  
WHEN id = 2 THEN 8  
... // could be hundreds more lines here  
ELSE attr_1   
END,  
CASE attr_2  
WHEN id = 1 THEN 96   
WHEN id = 2 THEN 45   
...  // could be hundreds more lines here  
ELSE attr_2   
END,  
... // and so on for each attribute`
```

Comment: We can't anwser without knowing table structure, used storage engine and used query.

Comment: I've added the data you ask for. You can now check it out in the post.

Comment: Building & using the case statement seems unlikely to be the right way to do whatever you are trying to do. Fill a table of attr_, id & int triplets and do an update per a join. Moreover one must wonder how much of getting the ints can also be done beneficially in the DBMS.

Comment: So what would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience in MySQL, it's wise to limit the size of your queries by character count.  If you keep your query character count to somewhere around 10K -
 20K characters or less, you will get decent efficiency. At the same time you won't risk overflowing any buffers.

Why are larger queries more efficient?  In the world of InnoDB, it's because each single queries is inherently a single transaction. Bulk updates done row by row can generate one transaction (one commit) per row. That slows things down.

Another way to get the efficiency is to wrap your update operations in a single transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE something SET col='val' WHERE id='id';
UPDATE something SET col='val' WHERE id='id';
UPDATE something SET col='val' WHERE id='id';
COMMIT;
```

This saves time because much of the time is consumed at COMMIT.  But if you put hundreds of thousands of operations in the transaction, it can swamp your server with a vast transaction.